# Interactive command line mode emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

Can anyone suggest any pointers / tutorials or information on how to get an interactive command-line mode in emacs. I have looked at comint and shell modes but these talk to a sub-process. I just want an interactive command line that talks to an elisp function, not a sub-process like `/bin/bash`. The idea is to use it to interact with simple interpreters written in elisp (just for fun).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ielm` for [inferior Emacs Lisp mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InferiorEmacsLispMode). You can get help by typing `(describe-mode)`<kbd>RET</kbd> at the prompt.

Strangely enough, it uses "a dummy process to keep comint happy" but the process isn't actually used to process your commands. If you want to replace `ielm-eval-input` with your own function you could probably hack that.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, but I'd like to make a mode that I can run and it just fires up my interpreter in a window. I do use ielm - it's very good.

Comment: Sounds like an idea. I'll look into that. Thanks.